# How can I calculate truth tables to show the results for statements such as 'p and q'?

Tags: python

I need to write some code in Python that produces a truth table for the following statements: p and q, p or q, if p then q, p if and only if q

Below is some code I've written already, but I am not sure where to go from here

```
def getSym(x):
    if x:
        return 'T'
    else:
        return 'F'

values = [True, False]

for p in values:
    for q in values:
        print(getSym(p), getSym(q), getSym(p and q))
```

I get:

```
(T T T)
(T F F)
(F T F)
(F F F)
```

but I am not sure how to get the last output which should be (T F T F)

Comment: What is `(T F T F)` supposed to be? There are only 2 inputs and 1 output, how can you have 4 values?

Comment: Your result is the full truth table.

Comment: @eatprawns77, I added an answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

You should apply what you have learned in your mathematical logic class, Next to what you have already implemented, I have added the truth table for `'p or q'`:

```
def getSym(x):
    if x:
        return 'T'
    else:
        return 'F'

values = [True, False]

print('and')
for p in values:
    for q in values:
        print(getSym(p), getSym(q), getSym(p and q))

print('or')
for p in values:
    for q in values:
        print(getSym(p), getSym(q), getSym(p or q))
```

For `'if p then q'` and `'p if and only if q'`, use the following equivalences:

- if p then q is `not p or q`
- p if and only if q is equivalent to `if p then q and if q then p` so apply the previous equivalence, and you will be able to implement it.

Hints:

- `getSym(not p or q)`
- `getSym((not p or q) and (not q or p))`

#### Observation:

You could improve your `getSym` function as follows:

```
def getSym(x):
    return 'T' if x else 'F'
```

Answer (score 1):

You are going in the right direction. You have already printed the truth table for AND.

In

```
(T T T)
(T F F)
(F T F)
(F F F)
```

The last column is the truth table of AND

Similarly, you can print the truth table for other logical operations. just change your print statement accordingly..

For instance, for OR, it should be

```
print(getSym(p), getSym(q), getSym(p or q))
```